# Editing multiple files

Tags: algorithm, file, jetbrains-ide

I have the following problem:

I want to add the same text to multiple files. Specifically, I want to add an extension to a .dart file I'm not sure if there is already a pre-defined way for this in JetBrains' products (maybe not, but Android Studio for example).

```
class <classname> <add text here> //like in my case extends Class
```

The process would be

1. I select a bunch of files
2. I define my text I want to add
3. To all the files where it finds `class` it skips the next word and inserts the input.

If you wanted to achieve this without manually copy-pasting, how would you do it?

Comment: **1)** Select desired files **2)** Invoke "Edit | Find | Replace in Files" via keyboard (otherwise #3 will not have some options) -- use RegEx option and make your find/replace patterns **3)** Use "Scope" option and specify "Selected Files" (or whatever other scope is more useful for you, you can even make your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @LazyOne

With your suggestion, using the following regex solved the problem

```
(class)(\s.*)(\{)
```

replace with

```
$1$2extends <class>$3
```